# Electroless Plating of Zinc onto Copper in NaOH Solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

I’m researching how the classic “alchemy” demonstration works in which zinc is plated onto a copper penny in a solution of sodium hydroxide. Most online resources refer to the electroplating of copper with zinc, which is not what I’m interested in. The [best article I’ve been able to find](http://www.rsc.org/images/alchemy_tcm18-188862.pdf) on the electroless plating of zinc onto copper is from the Royal Chemistry Society. However, I have several questions. The three reactions this article describes are:

$\ce{Zn(s) + 2NaOH(aq) + 2H2O(l) -> Na2Zn(OH)4(aq) + H2(g)}$, which is the “formation of sodium zincate”

$\ce{Zn(s) -> Zn^2+(aq) + 2e- }$, which is the “electrode reaction” at the “zinc electrode” and is “followed by the complexing of the zinc ions as $\ce{Zn(OH)4^2- (aq)}$”

$\ce{Zn(OH)4^2- (aq) + 2e- -> Zn(s) + 4OH- (aq)}$, which is the “electrode reaction” at the “copper electrode”

I really don’t understand how these three reactions come together to describe the plating of the zinc onto the copper. Specifically, I don’t understand:

1) What is the role of zincate, $\ce{Zn(OH)4^2- (aq)}$, in the reaction?

2) On the molecular level, how are the zinc and copper actually attached together?

3) How is this an electrochemical cell (i.e. how is electricity involved)? Where can I learn more about electrochemical cells?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An explanation is provided [in this reference](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed072p386). The idea is that the electrode reactions are

$\ce{Zn(s) + 4OH^- -> [Zn(OH)_4]^{2-} + 2e-}$
and

$\ce{[Zn(OH)_4]^{2-} + 2e- -> Zn(alloy) + 4OH^-}$

So the zinc powder remaining will go into solution and the zincate is reduced on the copper surface to form a form of zinc rich brass. Brass is an alloy and the atoms are held together via metallic bonding.